# angularjs ui-grid datetime picker was not working

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

grid for angularjs project. I need datetime picker for the filter. 
So I have used angular angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive for that
Now my filter text box shows the datetimepicker.

But when i change the date it doesn't trigger filter change event

Here is my code:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        paginationPageSizes  : [1],
        paginationPageSize   : 1,
        useExternalPagination: true,
        showGridFooter       : true,
        showColumnFooter     : true,
        enableFiltering      : true,
        useExternalFiltering : true,
        onRegisterApi        : function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

            $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function(){
                        console.log("teststs");
                angular.forEach(this.grid.columns, function(column){
                    console.log(column.filters[0].term);
                    if(column.filters[0].term)
                        $scope.searchParams[column.name] = column.filters[0].term;
                    else if(column.filters[0].term === null)
                        delete $scope.searchParams[column.name];
                });

                getPages(1, $scope.searchParams);
            });
        },
        columnDefs           : [
            { 
                field: 'createdAt',
                filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container"><input type="text" id="dt1" class="form-control input-sm" datetimepicker ng-model="colFilter.term" placeholder="RAMA" name="time"></div>', 
                cellFilter: 'date: "yyyy-MM-dd"'
            },
            { 
                field: 'updatedAt', 
                cellFilter: 'date: "' + ENV.dateFormat + '"'
            }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

on the change event of the datepicker, you could add:

```
$scope.gridPacksApi.core.raise.filterChanged();
```

to force the event.